# How to vectorize in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I would like to vectorize these two lines of code. I just recently learned about vectorization. I know how to vectorize the sumsurface line but I am not sure how to include the if statement, I would really like to vectorize the whole for loop and get rid of it. I want to vectorize to improve runtime the code I have right now runs very slow. I preallocated the arrays which helps improve runtime. I had forgotten to do that  previously. If I could get any help that would be much appreciated.

```
pH = linspace(2,12, 6000);
for j = 1:300
    nAsp = randi([10, 30],[1,1]);%865
    nGlu = randi([12, 38],[1,1]);%1074
    nLys = randi([11, 33],[1,1]);%930
    nArg = randi([10, 30],[1,1]);%879
    nCys = randi([2, 8],[1,1]); %214
    nTyr = randi([5, 17],[1,1]); %462
    nHis = randi([4, 12],[1,1]); %360   

    for i = 1: len;

        sumsurface(i) = (nAsp).*(-(10.^((pH(i)-asp) )./(10.^((pH(i)-asp) )+1)) )+ (nGlu).*(-(10.^((pH(i)-glu) )./(10.^((pH(i)-glu) )+1)))+(nCys).*(-(10.^((pH(i)-cys) )./(10.^((pH(i)-cys) )+1)))+ (nTyr).* (-(10.^((pH(i)-tyr) )./(10.^((pH(i)-tyr) )+1)))+ (nHis).*(1./(10.^((pH(i)-his) )+1))+ (nLys).*(1./(10.^((pH(i)-lys) )+1))+ (nArg).*(1/(10.^((pH(i)-arg) )+1));
        if sumsurface(i) < .01 && sumsurface(i) > -.01
            %disp(sumsurface(i));
            disp(pH(i));
            x(1+end) = pH(i);
            aspl(1+end) = nAsp;
            glul(1+end) = nGlu;
            cysl(1+end) = nCys;
            tyrl(1+end) = nTyr;
            hisl(1+end) = nHis;
            lysl(1+end) = nLys;
            argl(1+end) = nArg;                 

        end
    end    
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible vectorization:

```
%# data
len = 6000;
pH = linspace(2,12, len);

%# some constants (fill your values here)
asp = 0; glu = 0; cys = 0; tyr = 0; his = 0; lys = 0; arg = 0;

%# random parameters for each iteration
num = 300;
nAsp = randi([10 30], [num 1]);
nGlu = randi([12 38], [num 1]);
nLys = randi([11 33], [num 1]);
nArg = randi([10 30], [num 1]);
nCys = randi([2 8]  , [num 1]);
nTyr = randi([5 17] , [num 1]);
nHis = randi([4 12] , [num 1]);

params = [nAsp nGlu nCys nTyr nHis nLys nArg];
M = [
    - 10.^(pH-asp) ./ (1 + 10.^(pH-asp))
    - 10.^(pH-glu) ./ (1 + 10.^(pH-glu))
    - 10.^(pH-cys) ./ (1 + 10.^(pH-cys))
    - 10.^(pH-tyr) ./ (1 + 10.^(pH-tyr))
    1 ./ (1 + 10.^(pH-his))
    1 ./ (1 + 10.^(pH-lys))
    1 ./ (1 + 10.^(pH-arg))
];

%# iterations
sumsurface = zeros(num,len);
x = cell(num,1); p = cell(num,1);
for j=1:num
    sumsurface(j,:) = params(j,:)*M;

    idx =  abs(sumsurface(j,:)) < 0.01;
    if any(idx)
        x{j} = pH(idx);
        p{j} = params(j,:);    %# [aspl glul cysl tyrl hisl lysl argl]
    end
end
```

After running the code, the cell-arrays `x` and `p` will contain, for each iteration, the `pH` and `params` respectively that satisfy your equation: `-0.01<sumsurface<0.01` (if they exist).

Answer (score 3):

You can vectorize the whole algorithm. I'm not going to code it all out for you but here are some pointers to get you started:

- Use [REPMAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) to create an array that contains as many copies of `pH` as there are iterations, i.e. `len`.
- Change all those variables beginning with `n` from scalars to vectors. For example, `nAsp = randi([10, 30], [len, 1])`
- Use [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) to determine the indices of `sumsurface` that match your criteria, i.e. `index = find(sumsurface < 0.01 & sumsurface > -0.01);`.
- Create your desired vectors using `index`, e.g. `aspl = nAsp(index);`
- Rinse. Repeat.

Comment: I updated my code, I realized I left out an important part. I have a double for loop but the lengths of the vectors are different. I do not want pH vector to be the same length as the nAsp = randi([10, 30], [len, 1]) vector. Will it still be possible to vectorize this? thanks for the pointers